# finding directories with regex

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to find directories that begin with '6g' then a 2 letter state, and 4 digit number. an example directory would be /home/6gAL0533/

typically I copy to all directories starting with 6g using 
"find 6g* -maxdepth 0 -type d"
 but I am at a point now where I need  to copy files to particular directories based on their 4 digit number (for instance 0300 - 0500) but I cant seem to get the find command to work for me. I think i need to use regex with the single character "." like "find -type d -regex '6g..0[3-5]...' " but that returns no results. I am probably using regex syntax incorrectly, but I haven't found much info on using regex to find directories. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This should be tagged `find`, not `bash`, unless you want an answer that uses bash globs rather than find. find is an external command, not part of bash, and works the same way no matter what shell you use it with. (You could also legitimately tag it `unix` -- as `find` is a UNIX tool included in the POSIX specification).

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `find` for this at all, and you also don't need regular expressions; glob patterns are quite adequate (which means you can be compatible with POSIX find, rather than requiring a GNU-extended version):

```
shopt -s nullglob
dirs=( /home/6g[A-Za-z][A-Za-z]0[3-5][0-9][0-9][0-9] )
printf '%q\n' "${dirs[@]}" # print results
cp -- "${dirs[@]}" /to/destination # copy results somewhere else
```

...or...

```
dirs=( /home/6g??0[3-5]??? ) # use wildcards, as in your proposed regex
```

...or...

```
find /home -type d -maxdepth 1 -name '6g??0[3-5]???'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `find` regexes (as [Charles Duffy points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32078673/1566221), there are a variety of simpler solutions), you need to remember that `-regex` looks for *matches to the entire pathname*.

As documented in [`man find`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html):

```
-regex pattern
   File  name  matches  regular  expression  pattern.  This is a match
   on the whole path, not a search.  For example, to match a file
   named `./fubar3', you can use the regular expression `.*bar.' or
   `.*b.*3', but not `f.*r3'.  The regular expressions understood by
   find are by default Emacs Regular Expressions, but this can be
   changed with the -regextype option.
```

Consequently, you need:

```
find -type d -regex '.*/6g..0[3-5]...'
```